# Quarkus kafka set topic name from config file

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus

When I want to configure the customer and specify the name of the topic, it is not possible to specify this name from the config, as, for example, it was done using spring

Quarkus:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Consumer {
    
    @Incoming("topic-name")  //is it possible to pass the value from the config here?
    public void consume(String s) {
        Log.info(s);
    }
}
```

in spring it would look like this

```
@Incoming("${topic.name}")
```

application.yml

```
topic:
   name: topic-name
```

Is it possible to transfer the value from the config to the `@Incoming("value")` annotation in Quarkus?

Comment: so, what's the problem?

Comment: is it possible to transfer values ​​from the config in quarkus, as in spring?

Comment: No I meant that have you tried it, why it didn’t work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the 'channel name' instead of the 'topic name' in your @Incoming annotation.

Your java code would look like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Consumer {

   @Incoming("your-custom-channel-name")
   public void consume(String s) {
      Log.info(s);
   }
}
```

To be honest, I've never used the yml format, just the application.properties file. Here you would define the channel with each of its properties (like the topic):

```
mp.messaging.incoming.your-custom-channel-name.topic=your-topic-name
mp.messaging.incoming.your-custom-channel-name.auto.offset.reset=earliest
mp.messaging.incoming.your-custom-channel-name.group.id=${quarkus.kafka-streams.application-id}-my-private-group-id
```

I assume that if you would try to reformat this into your yml file, it would look like this (not tested):

```
mp:
  messaging:
    incoming: 
      your-custom-channel-name:
        topic: your-topic-name
        auto:
          offset:
            reset: earliest
        group:
          id: ${quarkus.kafka-streams.application-id}-my-private-group-id
```

Following this guide on the Quarkus website would give you a step-by-step approach on how to do this: [Reactive messaging with Kafka](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-reactive-getting-started)